# How to set coloration with os_log using swift and xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, logging, console

I set up logging yesterday in my project using `OSLog` and `os_log()`. I noticed that when I log using the OSLogTypes of `.info` and `.debug`, in the console, they're white. But when I use the OSLogType of `.error`, the console displays it with the color yellow and when I use `.fault`, the console displays it with the color red.

Is there a place I can set these colors?

I'm fine with all the colors, I just want `.debug` to show up as maybe purple or blue or orange or something different and noticeable.